# Google Places API request returns empty array but prints all responses - no error

Tags: arrays, swift3, google-places-api

I have the following error-free code and can't seem to use any of the information purposed for my results array. After playing around, I can print every businessID location listed but I can't add/use the array meant to hold this information. I do not understand why every location prints but my array appears as empty.

I apologize for the entirety of my code but I've spent hours trying to correct my issue...

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces

class FoodTwo: UITableViewController {

var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!

let international: [String] = ["ChIJAQDABX7CIogRIEY3k6r7R-g",
"ChIJqX3q1IbCIogRFcuI05IPNDU",
"ChIJAQDABX7CIogRY2MA6XVas8E"]

let american: [String] = ["ChIJkX9tTSvoIogROXkxd0gpg3s", "ChIJy7lUZCfoIogRVBuB9jWKHUk", "ChIJyzCZMiroIogRkuMavnKsA0w", "ChIJbYvWJ5jCIogRxh0VQA_yD0I", "ChIJa4Sks23CIogRpRod4v5GEN8", "ChIJxVpGsNbpIogRG5HIAKbNyDU", "ChIJ1W32UyvoIogRyp_Rdxn6f8I", "ChIJwTht4ifoIogRsuXdEOrKGMk", "ChIJ6UXEgNPpIogR4Q3ZAAWQQSI", "ChIJUZVAjdTpIogRpyca26a6D8o",                 "ChIJ6-h6_EctIIgRO1kypozaGGs", "ChIJK8NGam7CIogRlzU1TKeSjVI", "ChIJ7Xxh1m3CIogRZ_yabslUzd8", "ChIJ_dxSGJ7CIogRcYwJhjAm7TQ"]

 // more arrays here - deleted to reduce scrolling//

var results = [GMSPlace]()

var index: IndexPath!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
     var place: [String]

    switch index.row
    {
    case 0 :
        place = international
    case 1 :
        place = american
    case 2 :
        place = asian
    case 3 :
        place = bakery
    case 4 :
         place = bar
     case 5 :
      place = indian
     case 6 :
        place = italian
     default :
         place = mexican
    }
    for id in place
    {
        placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(id, callback: { (result, error) -> Void in

            if let error = error {
                print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

           guard let result = result
          else
           {
            print("No place details for \(id)")
            return
            }
        self.results.append(result)

        })
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation( { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
               })

        }
 }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return results.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FCT") as! FoodCellTwo

    let each = results[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = each.name

    return cell
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`placesClient.lookUpPlaceID` is an **asynchronous function**. You have to wait until it finishes. So, you are esentially reloading the table view *before* the array populates.

You should reload the table view **after** the array was filled.

```
for id in place {
    placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(id) { result, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let result = result else {
            print("No place details for \(id)")
            return
        }

        self.results.append(result)

        if place.count == self.results.count {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One more close bracket was needed ], but this was the answer!